# Implementation of Resilient Propagation

Tags: neural-network

Currently I am trying to implement Resilient Propagation for my network. I'm doing  this based on the encog implementation, but there is one thing I don't understand:

[The documentation](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Resilient_Propagation) for RPROP and iRPROP+ says when change > 0: weightChange = -sign(gradient) * delta

[The source code](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/neural/networks/training/propagation/resilient/ResilientPropagation.java) in lines 298 and 366 does not have a minus!

Since I assume both are in some case correct: Why is there a difference between the two?

And concerning the gradient: I'm using tanh as activion in the output layer. Is this the correct calculation of the gradient?

```
gradientOutput = (1 - lastOutput[j] * lastOutput[j]) * (target[j] - lastOutput[j]);
```

Answer (score 3):

After re-reading the relevant papers and looking up in a textbook I think the documentation of encog is not correct at this point. Why don't you just try it out by temporarily adding the minus-signs in the source code? If you use the same initial weights, you should receive exact the same results, given the documentation was correct. But in the end it just matters how you use the weightUpdate variable. If the author of the documentation is used to subtracting the weightUpdate from the weights instead of adding it, this will work.

**Edit**: I revisited the part about the gradient calculation in my original answer.

First, here is a brief explanation on how you can imagine the gradient for the weights in your output layer. First, you calculate the error between your outputs and the target values.

What you are now trying to do is to "blame" those neurons in the previous layer, which were active. Imagine the output neuron saying "Well, I have an error here, who is responsible?". Responsible are the neurons of the previous layer. Depending on the output being too small or too large compared to the target value, it will increase or decrease the weights to each of the neurons in the previous layers depending on how active they have been.

x is the activation of a neuron in the hidden layer.

o is the activation of the output neuron.

φ is the activation function of the output neuron, φ' its derivative.

**Edit2**: Corrected the part below. Added matrix style computation of backpropagation.

The error at each output neuron j is:

(1)  δ<sub>out, j</sub> = φ'(o<sub>j</sub>)(t - o<sub>j</sub>)

The gradient for the weight connecting the hidden neuron i with the output neuron j:

(2)  grad<sub>i, j</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> * δ<sub>out, j</sub>

The backpropagated error at each hidden neuron i with the weights w:

(3)  δ<sub>hid, i</sub> = φ'(x)*∑w<sub>i, j</sub> * δ<sub>out, j</sub>

By repeatedly applying formula 2 and 3, you can backpropagate up to the input layer.

**Written in loops**, regarding one training sample:

The error at each output neuron j is:

```
for(int j=0; j < numOutNeurons; j++) {
  errorOut[j] = activationDerivative(o[j])*(t[j] - o[j]);
}
```

The gradient for the weight connecting the hidden neuron i with the output neuron j:

```
for(int i=0; i < numHidNeurons; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j < numOutNeurons; j++) {
    grad[i][j] = x[i] * errorOut[j]        
  }      
}
```

The backpropagated error at each hidden neuron i:

```
for(int i=0; i < numHidNeurons; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j < numOutNeurons; j++) {
    errorHid[i] = activationDerivative(x[i]) * weights[i][j] * errorOut[j]        
  }      
}
```

In fully connected Multilayer Perceptrons without convolution or anything like that you can can use **standard matrix operations**, which is a lot faster.

Assuming each of your samples is a row in your input matrix and the columns are its attributes, you can propagate the input through your network like this:

```
activations[0] = input;
for(int i=0; i < numWeightMatrices; i++){
  activations[i+1] = activations[i].dot(weightMatrices[i]);
  activations[i+1] = activationFunction(activations[i+1]);
}
```

Backpropagation then becomes:

```
n = numWeightMatrices;
error = activationDerivative(activations[n]) * (target - activations[n]);
for (int l=n-1; l >= 0; l--){
  gradient[l] = activations[l].transposed().dot(error);
  if (l > 0) {
     error = error.dot(weightMatrices[l].transposed());
     error = activationDerivative(activations[l])*error;
  }
}
```

I omitted the bias neuron in the above explanations. In literature it is recommended to model the bias neuron as an additional column in each activation matrix which is alway 1.0 . You will need to deal with some slice assigns. When using the matrix backpropagation loop, do not forget to set the error at the position of the bias to 0 before each step!

Comment: Are you sure (1.0 - hiddenActivation[i]*hiddenActivation[i]) is correct? I used (1.0 - lastOutput[j]*lastOutput[j]) for simple backpropagation and it worked. I'm asking since it still doesn't work as expected :/

Comment: Yes sorry, there was another error; I took some more time, corrected it and added a suggestion on how you can use matrix operations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The backpropagation now works perfectly. I am still having problems with resilient propagation. I copied the implementation of encog and used the whole framework, there seems to be something wrong with their implementation.

Comment: I am still having problems with the implementation of resilient propagation. Would you be so kind and have a look at my source code? http://pastebin.com/mfQFhqLW Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
private float resilientPropagation(int i, int j){
    float gradientSignChange = sign(prevGradient[i][j]*gradient[i][j]);
    float delta = 0;
    if(gradientSignChange > 0){
        float change = Math.min((prevChange[i][j]*increaseFactor), maxDelta);
        delta = sign(gradient[i][j])*change;
        prevChange[i][j] = change;
        prevGradient[i][j] = gradient[i][j];
    }
    else if(gradientSignChange < 0){
        float change = Math.max((prevChange[i][j]*decreaseFactor), minDelta);
        prevChange[i][j] = change;
        delta = -prevDelta[i][j];
        prevGradient[i][j] = 0;
    }
    else if(gradientSignChange == 0){
        float change = prevChange[i][j];
        delta = sign(gradient[i][j])*change;
        prevGradient[i][j] = gradient[i][j];
    }
    prevDelta[i][j] = delta;
    return delta;       
}


gradient[i][j] = error[j]*layerInput[i];
weights[i][j]= weights[i][j]+resilientPropagation(i,j);
```